# Can I have a multi-page React app without a Node.js server?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, multi-page-application

I want to develop a multi-page React app, where you have multiple HTML files instead of a single HTML with routes. However, so far all the solutions I found require a Node.js server.

After much struggle I eventually wrote a webpack config file to generate multiple HTML files myself, which generates multiple HTML files according to a certain file name pattern that I defined. The config file, however, is not something easy to maintain.

Then I wonder: isn't there a standard solution for that?

Comment: A React-based static site generator? See e.g. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a part of the pure React library, but quite a few frameworks that are based off React have a routing and html-generating solution for you.

Have a look at [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/routing/), which is what I use for your exact scenario.

> Each .js file inside src/pages will generate its own page in your Gatsby site. The path for those pages matches the file structure it’s found in.